# Android: building with Gradle, signing with maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle, zipalign

My Android build works fine in Continuous Integration, except for androidSigning: Gradle can allow for a developer to catch the keystore path and passwords in clear. Which is not satisfactory.

1- Have you a workaround for that? Such as password encryption...
2- My idea is now to build with Gradle, and sign and zipalign with Maven.

Currently I succeed in signing an existing apk, but cannot zipalign the signed apk. Here is the **pom.xml** located in the **app** folder:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sign</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>signing</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>

                            ... all parameters ok...

                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.2</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <sign>
                            <debug>false</debug>
                        </sign>
                        <zipalign>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <inputApk>${apk.build.directory}/app-release-unsigned.apk</inputApk>
                            <outputApk>${apk.build.directory}/app-release-signed-aligned.apk</outputApk>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </zipalign>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>alignApk</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>zipalign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Results is

```
[INFO] --- maven-jarsigner-plugin:1.4:sign (signing) @ mavensigning ---
[INFO] 1 archive(s) traitées
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:zipalign (alignApk) @ mavensigning ---
[INFO] Skipping zipalign on pom
```

Any idea why I cannont perform zipalign?